# Objective-c, strange behaviour when iterating over an empty NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I don't understand what is happening with this piece of code:

The sortedArray, which is a NSMutableArray, is empty, so, the value of sortedArray.count is 0.

> ```
>      for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < (sortedArray.count -1) ; i++) 
>          NSLog(@"Apparently %d < %d  ( [sortedArray count] %d)", i, sortedArray.count-1, [sortedArray count] );
> ```

Consequently, we should never enter the loop, but  I see the following in the log:

> 2014-01-21 12:11:16.433 AppName[445:60b] Apparently 0 < -1  (
>   [sortedArray count] 0)

Does anybody has an idea of what can trigger the problem?

Comment: That's normal i = 0, and i should be less than 0 (array count) -1, which equals -1. So (i = 0 && i < -1). That's sound right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(sortedArray.count -1)
```

is an unsigned integer 0 trying to subtract one from itself, so your `-1` is being interpreted as `NSUIntegerMax`

Comment: What got me is that fact that printing (sortedArray.count -1) in the log printed -1 . Using %d caused a conversion to a signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) just use:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sortedArray.count; i++)
```

because the test `i < sortedArray.count` will return `NO` as 0 is not less than 0. You current code, if the array had content, would not iterate the last object in the array.

Comment: This is actually the point: I'm comparing the ith element with the i+1th element in the loop (not shown here). Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your logic your condition should be:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i <= (sortedArray.count -1) ; i++)
```

or

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < sortedArray.count ; i++)
```

In your example you subtract 1 from zero which gives you -1 so -1 is less that (sortedArray.count -1) so the condition is true and it enters to the loop.